# Standard include Paths entries for GCC with Eclipse Kepler on Linux Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc, include

I am using Eclipse Kepler (Service Release 2) on Linux Ubuntu 13.10.

Trying to build a "hello world" project (created using File->New->C++Project->HelloWorldC++Project) results in

`unresolved inclusion: < iostream >`

Under Project Properties:
C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols
I see that there is no include directory given under any of "Assembly", "GNU C" or "GNU C++".

Setting/deleting the checkmark at "Show built-in values" doesn't help.
Also not helping is trying to clear the discovery entries under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options.

I would be very pleased if anyone could tell me either
- how to get Eclipse auto-setting the necessary standard include paths
or
- tell me which paths I actualy need to set myself to get a simple hello-World C++ project running

Thanks in advance.

Steve